# Returning a new JSON object with filtered results

Tags: javascript, json, object, filter

I'm looking to return a new JS object from an existing JS object, after filtering for some result.

Say I have the following JS object:

```
{ "Examples" : 
  [ { "id": 1, "name": "Tim", "answer": "yes"},
    { "id": 2, "name": "Jon", "answer": "no"},
    { "id": 3, "name": "Don", "answer": "yes" ] }
```

I want to filter through this object for all yes answers and return an object that looks like this:

```
{ "Examples" :
  [ { "id" : 1, "name": "Tim", "answer": "yes"},
    { "id" : 3, "name": "Don", "answer": "yes"} ] }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: that's a JavaScript object, not a JSON object. JSON is a serialization scheme.

You can filter the array with `.filter()`:

```
var obj = { "Examples" : 
[ { "id": 1, "name": "Tim", "answer": "yes"},
  { "id": 2, "name": "Jon", "answer": "no"},
  { "id": 3, "name": "Don", "answer": "yes" ] };

obj.Examples = obj.Examples.filter(function(entry) {
  return entry.answer === "yes";
});
```